# "VerifyError: StackMapTable error: bad offset" at the first instruction of a method in instrumented class

Tags: java, jvm, instrumentation, java-bytecode-asm, .class-file

I used ASM to instrument a class file, and the instrumented class throws VerifyError. The error message is like:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: StackMapTable error: bad offset
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/joda/time/TestAllPackages.suite()Ljunit/framework/Test; @0: invokestatic
  Reason:
    Invalid stackmap specification.
  Current Frame:
    bci: @88
    flags: { }
    locals: { }
    stack: { }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: b800 5bb6 005f 3f1e 1276 b800 67bb 0002
    0x0000010: 59b7 0003 4d2c b800 04b6 0005 2cb8 0006
    0x0000020: b600 052c b800 07b6 0005 2cb8 0008 b600
    0x0000030: 052c b800 09b6 0005 2cb8 000a b600 052c
    0x0000040: b800 0bb6 0005 2c1e 1276 b800 74b0 a700
    0x0000050: 0a1e 1276 b800 74bf                    
  Exception Handler Table:
    bci [0, 78] => handler: 81
  Stackmap Table:
    same_locals_1_stack_item_extended(@81,Object[#85])
    same_frame(@88)

    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit3.JUnit3Reflector.createInstanceFromSuiteMethod(JUnit3Reflector.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit3.JUnit3Reflector.constructTestObject(JUnit3Reflector.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit.JUnitTestSet.execute(JUnitTestSet.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit.JUnit3Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit3Provider.java:140)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit.JUnit3Provider.invoke(JUnit3Provider.java:113)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:379)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:340)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:125)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:413)
```

And the instrumented class is rather simple: [org.joda.time.TestAllPackages.class](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DvuhV0ISXa3SLnCqzRRwz-jT4JZU1WIK/view?usp=sharing). I inserted those stackmap frames use `visitFrames` manually (didn't use COMPUTE_FRAMES which is painful) because I want to correctly write `visitFrames` by myself.

I really want to know what is happening, i.e., what is the problem with the class file since I did not discover anything suspicious.

Thanks!

---

BTW, my instrumentation code is like:

```
...
    private Label tryStart = new Label();
    private Label tryEnd = new Label();
    private Label catchStart = new Label();
    private Label catchEnd = new Label();

    public XxxMethodVisitor(MethodVisitor mv, String methodName, int access, String desc, String className, boolean isStatic, boolean isPublic) {
        super(Config.ASM_VERSION, mv);
        this.methodName = methodName;
        this.className = className;
        this.selfDesc = desc;
        selfReturnType = Type.getReturnType(desc);
        selfMethodId = String.format("%s%c%s%c%s", className, SEPARATOR, methodName, SEPARATOR, desc);
        this.isStatic = isStatic;
        this.isPublic = isPublic;
    }

    // start of the method
    public void visitCode() {
        mv.visitCode();
//        mv.visitFrame(F_NEW, initLocals.length, initLocals, 0, new Object[]{});
        mv.visitTryCatchBlock(tryStart, tryEnd, catchStart, "java/lang/Throwable");
        mv.visitLabel(tryStart);
        ...
    }

    public void visitEnd() {
        mv.visitLabel(tryEnd);
        mv.visitJumpInsn(GOTO, catchEnd);
        mv.visitLabel(catchStart);
        // exception caught
        mv.visitFrame(F_SAME1, 0, null, 1, new Object[] {"java/lang/Throwable"});
        ...
        mv.visitInsn(ATHROW);
        mv.visitLabel(catchEnd);
        mv.visitFrame(F_SAME, 0, null, 0, null);
        super.visitEnd();
    }
```

Comment: You've missed `return` instruction at the end of the method. As @boneill noticed, `goto` cannot point beyond the last instruction.

Comment: As a side note, `String.format("%s%c%s%c%s", className, SEPARATOR, methodName, SEPARATOR, desc)` is a very inefficient way to express `className + SEPARATOR + methodName + SEPARATOR + desc`. If you prefer higher level constructs, express your actual intention: `String.join(SEPARATOR, className, methodName, desc)`

Comment: @Holger Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why the verify error is complaining about the stack map table, when there's a much more glaring problem: the `goto` instruction is branching to offset 84, which is just past the end of the `suite` method. This is what I found when checking the class that you linked to. The dump from the verify error looks different, but it references "bci: @88", which is also out of bounds.

Comment: “much more glaring” is a human’s perspective. The verifier has to start its checking at one point and since the stack maps are supposed to help verifying the bytecode instructions (to be able to do it in one pass), it makes sense to check the validity of the stack map first.